# How to fetch ExternalID, SystemID and InternalSubset from an xmlNodePtr that has type=XML_DOCUMENT_TYPE_NODE or XML_DTD_NODE

Tags: c++, xml, libxml2

I need 3 values (ExternalID, SystemID, InternalSubset) from xmlNodePtr when it is of type XML_DOCUMENT_TYPE_NODE or XML_DTD_NODE.

I noticed that [XML_DOCUMENT_TYPE_NODE is deprecated and that you recommend using XML_DTD_NODE](https://github.com/GNOME/libxml2/blob/5f54bac9ebfc1486c9180b581e32588ee74c59e4/include/libxml/tree.h#L156). Given, an xmlNodePtr which has type=XML_DOCUMENT_TYPE_NODE or XML_DTD_NODE, how can fetch those 3 values.

I also noticed that in Android Open Source Code [here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/libxml2/+/b730f8d3c15da4ac439f1184bf17a13021963ea9/tree.c#4334) they have directly typecasted xmlNodePtr to xmlDtdPtr. Is this possible? If yes, we can get ExternalID and SystemID from xmlDtdPtr.